# AmazonMQ with .NET Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

Has anyone managed to get connect to AmazonMQ using .NET Core 2.0 over SSL?

I'm getting following error using the Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Core package to connect:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The requested security protocol is not supported.
   at System.Net.SecurityProtocol.ThrowOnNotAllowed(SslProtocols protocols, Boolean allowNone)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.Tcp.SslTransport.CreateSocketStream()
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.Tcp.TcpTransport.Start()
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.WireFormatNegotiator.Start()
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.CheckConnected()
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.CreateActiveMQSession(AcknowledgementMode ackMode)
   at SendToMQ.Program.SendMessage() in C:\GITLab\POC\SendToMQ\SendToMQ\SendToMQ\Program.cs:line 40
   at SendToMQ.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\GITLab\POC\SendToMQ\SendToMQ\SendToMQ\Program.cs:line 15
```

Using the following code:

```
string url = "ssl://url:61617";
string userName = "name";
string password = "pw";


string payLoad = "This is a test.";
IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(new Uri(url));

using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection(userName, password))
{
    using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge))
    {

        IDestination destination = Apache.NMS.Util.SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "TestTopic");
        using (IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination))
        {
            connection.Start();

            ITextMessage request = session.CreateTextMessage(payLoad);
            request.Properties["id"] = 123;
            producer.Send(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to create an SslFactory and set the SslOption specificallly to Tls.
Else, NMS defaults to SslProtocol.Default (in Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.Tcp.SslTransport.GetAllowedProtocol() ), which is Ssl3.

```
        String uri = "ssl://yourinstance:61617?nms.AsyncSend=true";
        ITransportFactory sslTransportFactory = new SslTransportFactory();
        ((SslTransportFactory)sslTransportFactory).SslProtocol = "Tls";
        ITransport transport = sslTransportFactory.CreateTransport(new Uri(uri));
        Connection connection = new Connection(new Uri(uri), transport, new IdGenerator())
        {
            UserName = "user",
            Password = "pwd"
        };
        ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
        IDestination dest = session.GetQueue("my_queue");
        IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(dest);
        producer.DeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.NonPersistent;
        var msg = session.CreateTextMessage("Some msg");
        producer.Send(msg);
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Thanks @jorrrit-visser saved me plenty of pain right before deployment.

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver! ♥